# Can I provider credentials for terraform import operation?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm writing a terraform provider and there're 2 types of credentials: global (that are being set in `provider` block) and local (that are set for each resource).

The problem is that both of them in order to import a resource, it it a reasonable idea to pass them in `terraform import` command and then parse its composed ID as a resource ID and its credentials? I.e.,

```
terraform import my_provider.my_example_resource abc123/LOCAL_ABC123_USERNAME/LOCAL_ABC123_PASSWORD
```

I took a look at SDK's [code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/9dad6ed9dc7845584ce20f1116c02a10863b1900/helper/schema/resource_importer.go#L36-L37) and there's a quote:

> StateContextFunc is the function called to import a resource into the Terraform state. It is given a ResourceData with only ID set. This ID is going to be an arbitrary value given by the user and may not map directly to the ID format that the resource expects, so that should be validated.

so I can't really expect to work the following configuration:

```
provider {...}
resource "my_provider" "my_example_resource" {
   local_username = "foo"
   local_password = "bar"
}
```

since when I run `terraform import my_provider.my_example_resource` I won't be able to access its `local_username / local_password` properties.

Comment: This will probably not be possible. This would likely either require a fix for the API or a workaround for the bindings.